# Creating a name space for OpenSSL Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl

Is it possible to create a separate namespace when compiling the OpenSSL Lib?  I'm using https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.

The reason I need this is because the current SDK I'm building uses OpenSSL, but when I pass it to the customer, they also uses a different version of OpenSSL, and it is causing duplicate symbol linker errors.

Another question is there a different way for the customer to use our existing SDK without defining our own name space for the OpenSSL Lib?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL is a C library. And C does not support namespaces.

If you really have naming conflicts, best way to handle this is using a wrapper library.

Just as illustration a small example.

wrapper.h:

```
void xxxxxOpenSSLFunction1();
void xxxxxOpenSSLFunction2();
void xxxxxOpenSSLFunction3();
```

wrapper.cpp

```
#include <OpenSSL...>
#include <OpenSSL...>

void xxxxxOpenSSLFunction1() { OpenSSLFunction1(); }
void xxxxxOpenSSLFunction2() { OpenSSLFunction2(); }
void xxxxxOpenSSLFunction3() { OpenSSLFunction3(); }
```